# How to set a pixel using GIL iterators

Tags: c++, boost, boost-gil

Trying to learn a bit of C++ and I am very new at it. My learning project is to generate images using various algorythms (like fractals). I am looking at the boost GIL library, since boost seems to be the most common and established C++ library around. So, I am trying to create an image in memory, iterate over pixels and set the RGB value based on some formula. My current code looks like this

```
int main() {
    rgb8_image_t img(IMAGE_W, IMAGE_H);
    auto b = view(img).begin();
    while (b != view(img).end()) {
        /* set the pixel value here */
        b++;
    }
    write_view("image.png", view(img), png_tag());
    return 0;
}
```

The iteration seems to work, but I cannot seem to figure out from the GIL docs, how to actually set the pixel in this loop. I could do a nested for loop and just set pixels using x and y coordinates, but I kinda want to use iterators since it seems neater and maybe I can later refactor this to use transform(). How do I proceed from here? How do I set a pixel to some RGB value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, create value of type of `rgb8_pixel_t` with desired channel values and assign it to the pixel pointed by iterator.

For a simple example, this will fill your image with solid orange:

```cpp
#include <boost/gil.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/png.hpp>
namespace gil = boost::gil;

int main()
{
    gil::rgb8_image_t img(100, 100);
    auto v = gil::view(img);
    auto b = v.begin();
    while (b != v.end())
    {
        *b = gil::rgb8_pixel_t{255, 128, 0};
        b++;
    }
    gil::write_view("image.png", gil::view(img), gil::png_tag());
}
```

For a more complex example, here is how to use a custom generator of pixel channel values:

```cpp
#include <boost/gil.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/png.hpp>
#include <random>
namespace gil = boost::gil;

template <typename T>
struct random_value
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "T must be integral type");
    static constexpr auto range_min = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
    static constexpr auto range_max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();

    random_value() : rng_(rd_()), uid_(range_min, range_max) {}

    T operator()()
    {
        auto value = uid_(rng_);
        return static_cast<T>(value);
    }

    std::random_device rd_;
    std::mt19937 rng_;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<typename gil::promote_integral<T>::type> uid_;
};

int main()
{
    random_value<channel_type<gil::rgb8_pixel_t>::type> make_channel_value;

    gil::rgb8_image_t img(100, 100);
    auto v = gil::view(img);
    auto b = v.begin();
    while (b != v.end())
    {
        // generate random value for each channel of RGB image separately
        gil::static_generate(*b, [&make_channel_value]() { return make_channel_value(); });
        b++;
    }
    gil::write_view("image.png", gil::view(img), gil::png_tag());
}
```

UPDATE: The `static_generate` is one of [GIL algorithms to operate on color bases](https://github.com/boostorg/gil/blob/c3e84adbd730205ba601477492eb0fbc9ff2c230/doc/design_guide.rst#algorithms-1) (e.g. pixels). The `struct random_value` is a functor class because it encapsulates data elements of the random number generator. I simply copied it form GIL's [test/core/image/test_fixture.hpp](https://github.com/boostorg/gil/blob/5d69ccf987f5b8020007af993c1713052bcdf48a/test/core/image/test_fixture.hpp), but it does not have to be a class. It can be anything callable, usable as a functor.
I have updated the code snippets with `gil::` namespace qualification to make it clearer where things come from.

Comment: And now I feel stupid and don't know why I couldn't make it work :)

Comment: Why are you using a struct in the "advanced" example? And where does static_generate() come from?

Comment: @MadWombat I have added update to my answer to address your questions.